# Visual Studio "resource" project type?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, solution

In Eclipse, you can create a "resource" project type which is basically just a folder with some files in it but visible as a separate project in the "solution". How to do that in Visual Studio?

Solution folders seem close but I don't think it's possible to add a solution folder from an existing folder on a disk, is it?

For example, I have a folder named `Build` with some build files and nested folders in it. I want to be able to edit these files directly from Visual Studio, how do I make them visible in solution folder without manually recreating folder structure using solution folders etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is to add an empty website to a solution - though it defines some unnecessary things like web server configuration, it mirrors file system and that is the main thing.

Right-click solution -> Add -> Add New Website... -> Empty Website

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't just add/import an existing folder and all its sub-folders in one action, and Visual Studio does not have the concept of a "resource" project type, as you describe it. You can (as you suggest) use Solution folders for this purpose, however, you must first recreate the folder hierarchy in the Solution Explorer, like so:

- R-click on the project folder (or any sub-folder) and choose "Add" -> "New Folder" (for C# projects), or "Add" -> "New Filter" (for C++ projects). Then type the name of the folder you want to add. (`Build`, in your example)
- R-click on the newly created folder (still in Solution Explorer) and choose "Add" -> "Existing Item...". Then browse to the corresponding folder on disk, and multi-select all the files/items in that folder which you want to add.
- Repeat this process for all sub-folders.

(Note that the folder structure in the Solution Explorer is not required to match the hierarchy on disk. This allows you, for example, to place all your header files and source files in separate folders in the Solution Explorer, but keep them in one folder on disk.)

Comment: Hmm, what if I later move files in either solution folder or a file-system folder? Will this change be reflected on the other side? I'm starting to think that maybe I would be better off just editing the files outside of Visual Studio.

Comment: @Borek: From Solution Explorer you have two options: (1) Remove (which removes the file from the Solution, but not from disk), and (2) Delete (which removes it from the solution and deletes it from disk. Moving a file in Solution Explorer has no impact on file-system location. When working in Windows Explorer, I believe deleting a file will also remove it from the Solution, (though i haven't tested this lately). I'm not sure about a move -- give it a test and find out. I recommend that once you add a file to the Solution, you always work on it from within VS